# How to obtain the Relic of Xuen

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I was curious if someone can explain how one can obtain the powerful trinket at the Darkmoon Faire? Where does it start? How long does it take? The faire starts today, I believe. Any information on how to obtain this as fast as possible would be great. Here is the link to it on wowhead, but I find the comments not helpful:

http://www.wowhead.com/item=79328

Comment: As long as your on WoWhead, try looking at the comments. The answer is right there. It is a reward from the "Tiger Deck", created through Inscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like the preivous card decks, the new Darkmoon decks require you to combine all eight cards of the same deck to start the quest.

In the case of the [Tiger Deck](http://www.wowhead.com/item=79323), you need the eight Tiger cards starting from [the Ace of Tigers](http://www.wowhead.com/item=79283) all the way to [the Eight of Tigers](http://www.wowhead.com/item=79290).

These cards are created by players with the Inscription profession and are often available for sale on the AH. In previous expansions they can also be dropped by dungeon and raid elites and have roughly the same droprate as any random blue rares; I am not sure if this is the case in Mists of Pandaria.